# synchronize on 2 elements of array Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, synchronized

I need to achieve atomic update of two elements in an 2D array of objects. 
The objects represent whether something can be stored in the array at a position (x,y) and if something is already stored what type it is. So the objects themselves are not to be changed but their internal state is.

I am currently using 2 nested synchronize statements with which I am synchronizing access to two elements in the array:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < storage.length; i++) {
            synchronized (storage[i][j]) {
                synchronized (storage[i+1][j]) {
                    if (storage[i][j].isfree() && storage[i+1][j].isfree())
                        return (storage[i][j].store(true)&&storage[i+1][j].store(true));
                }
            }
            synchronized (storage[i][j]) {
                synchronized (storage[i][j+1]) {
                    if (storage[i][j].isfree() && storage[i][j+1].isfree())
                        return (storage[i][j].store(true)&&storage[i+1][j+1].store(true));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am looping through the array looking for free slots (where I can store an item taking up two slots) and enter the two synchronized blocks unconditionally. Inside the second block I check whether two slots in the array are empty if so I store a new item. Otherwise I move to the next array element.

My question is does this work ? Will the updates be atomic when multiple Threads execute this code. Or is there a better way to achieve the same results. But mostly my question is the first one.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why are you using arrays for this?

Comment: Why not make an object holding the two other as children?

Comment: I have many slots in my storage where each one (or two) can hold an item. Some items occupy one slot some occupy two slots. Hence in some cases the need arises to synchronize on two slots.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: synchronisation points are potentially **costly**. Your code syncs on **twice** on each array element (and probably that code runs inside **another** loop). That is simply something you absolutely want to avoid.

Instead: create a helpful abstraction. In other words: that class that actually populates your array - give that a method that does the required work. And then, make that method synchronize internally!

Comment: This is the method that does the work. But it needs to find two empty slots in the 2d table. Of course it has to iterate through the array until it finds two slots. I don't see way other than iterating through the array and locking 2 slots at the same time. And I can only find out inside synchronized blocks - otherwise some other thread could have filled a slot in the meantime. Maybe I am wrong and there is another thread-safe way doing this ? Can you please share what your idea was ? Thanks